# UseLayoutRounding and Grid star sizing causing an infinite layout loop

Tags: wpf, layout, infinite-loop

I have a strange issue with WPF layouting that I've now tracked down to the following situation. The window has a Grid with two columns, both star-sized to separate the width in two halfs. Also, the window has set UseLayoutRounding=True to prevent that stupid between-pixels rendering that WPF usually does when it stops thinking. The left column contains a subclassed Panel and I have code access to its MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods. Tracing out its invocations and arguments, I see that both methods are called infinitely, alternatingly, with a measure size of like 532;400 and an arrange size of 533;400. This is one pixel more than before. Of course this triggers all sorts of invalidations and in the end, the whole layout process is restarted. This leads to all sorts of rendering errors in the entire application and one CPU core is fully loaded with this alone.

This issue only happens every 4 pixels in window width. I can control the window size through my application settings file so I can easily see and reproduce it. Three widths are good, the fourth is bad. So there's a 25 % chance of hitting the bug.

I've noticed this off-by-one-and-back situation elsewhere already, also with SharedSizeGroups in Grids, but after a few seconds it would eventually settle on something. This time, it sits there spinning forever.

I could surely determine this 1 pixel difference and break the loop with a nasty hack, but then I fear that something is rendered that 1 pixel off and it looks ugly. I'd rather make WPF not tell my control inconsistent size values in the first place, but decide on one and stay with it.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says:

> When you use layout rounding and Star sizing, the layout system creates small variations in the column or row measurements to avoid subpixel rendering. For example, if a grid has a total width of 100 with 3 columns each of size Star, instead of creating three columns that have an equal width of 33.3, the layout system creates 2 columns that have a width of 33 and one that has a width of 34.

That seems to be a bit unstable to me.

What can I do to fix WPF's behaviour?

Comment: Code example please :)

Comment: You need an example for a two-column star-sized Grid and the tracing of call parameters of two standard layout methods? Well, I'll see what I can do to make it brief.

Comment: Give me an example where you resize the window and grid freezes the ui because it runs into that infinity loop

Comment: I've easily seen the differing sizes in MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride but wasn't able to cause that infinite layout loop. From further analysing my trace log, I found that UpdateScrollInfo (which calls InvalidateMeasure on size change) was called in both functions. Leaving it out in MeasureOverride fixed the issue, seemingly with no other issues. Should I close this question now?

Comment: You can turn this in a discussion if you want but post code

Comment: We just hit an issue where UseLayoutRounding was also causing a freeze.  It was quite painful to track down.  We instrumented the freezing view's implementation of ArrangeOverride and saw ArrangeOverride was not completing.  Just noting this so people can find this googling.  Our fix was to stop using UseLayoutRounding.  The issue came up when we changed our .NET SDK target from 4.5.2 to 4.7.1.  It didn't repro when we targetted 4.6.1.

Comment: Ahh the reason this happened on some machines is because their display setting for "change size of text, apps, and other items" was a non-default value of 150%

Comment: Sorry to dig out an old topic, but I'm just encountering the same problem and kind of driving me nuts. I tried to disable all UseLayoutRounding, all SnapsToDevicePixels, changed all Grid sizing from Star to Auto, removed all SharedSizeGroup, still the problem remains. I use .NET Framework 4.7. I tried the two stared columns Grid with the same version but I can't repro the lock. @ygoe What did you mean by "Leaving it out in MeasureOverride fixed the issue" ?